# the joption pane confirm dialog is not recognizing the no option

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

The confirm dialog box is not recognizing the no option. It prints yes no matter what i press. Can anyone help?

```
if(e.getSource()==b5)
{
int db=0;
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Exit this        

screen?","Exit",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

if(db==JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
{
System.out.println("no");
}
else if(db==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
{
System.out.println("yes");

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You havent assign JOptionPane return value to db, it should be

```
db = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Exit this screen", Exit",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code leaves `db` as zero, instead of assigning the return value of `showConfirmDialog` to it.  You meant to write this.

```
int db = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Exit this screen?", "Exit", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```